# $\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}} \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let a,b,c $\in \mathbb Q$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ then all roots of $m_{\alpha,\mathbb Q}(x)$ is in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

I want to show the above question.

But when $\alpha, \sqrt{c} \notin \mathbb Q$, I need to show that $\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}} \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ because of $m_{a,Q}(x)=x^4-2ax+(a^2-bc^2)$

I want to show the case only with calculation. Help me!

Comment: Is this true?  If $a=c=1, b=2$ you are trying to prove that $\sqrt {-1}\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: @lulu in your case, the assumption is wrong because $\sqrt{c} \in \mathbb Q$

Comment: If you want to exclude the case $\sqrt c\in \mathbb Q$, then take $a=1,b=c=2$.  Then you are claiming that $\sqrt {1-2\sqrt 2} \in \mathbb Q\left(\sqrt {1+2\sqrt 2}\right)$ but the left hand is complex and the right hand is totally real.

Comment: But maybe I am just not understanding your question.  Can you clearly state what you are assuming and what you want to prove?

Comment: I want to divide the case when i) $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ ii)$\alpha \notin \mathbb Q, \sqrt{c} \in \mathbb Q$ iii) $\alpha \notin \mathbb Q, \sqrt{c} \notin \mathbb Q$ where minimal polynomial is changed. But I think this problem have some mistake. I found this problem in Stephan Lovett's abstract algebra in chapter 7.2 exercise 10

Comment: Yes, I think something is confused here.  Maybe the problem referred to a splitting field?  In any case, it's hard to make sense of it as it stands.

Comment: The chapter is algebraic extension without splitting field and algebraic closure. Thank you for finding error.

Comment: Well, good luck sorting it out.